# ¿Como convertir de minúsculas a mayúsculas las primeras letras de cada palabra en un input? sin mover el puntero

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente convierto de minúsculas a mayúsculas las primeras letras de cada palabra en los `inputs`, pero quisiera evitar que a la hora del usuario querer insertar una palabra entre otra el puntero no se mueva al final a cada rato. ¿Existe la posibilidad?

```js
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if(!(
        e.keyCode == 9 || 
        e.keyCode == 16 || 
        e.keyCode == 17 || 
        e.keyCode == 18 || 
        e.keyCode == 32 || 
        e.keyCode == 37 || 
        e.keyCode == 38 || 
        e.keyCode == 39 || 
        e.keyCode == 40  
    )){ 
        if (e.originalEvent.repeat)
            e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});

$('#nombre').keyup(function(){
  $(this).val(MayusculaFrase($(this).val()));
});

function MayusculaFrase(string){
    var arrayWords;
    var returnString = "";
    var len;
    arrayWords = string.split(" ");
    len = arrayWords.length;
    for(i=0;i < len ;i++){
        if(i !== (len-1)){
            returnString = returnString+MayusculaPrimera(arrayWords[i])+" ";
        }else{
            returnString = returnString+MayusculaPrimera(arrayWords[i]);
        }
    }
    return returnString;
}

function MayusculaPrimera(string){
    return string.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+string.substr(1,string.length).toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un código que lo hace:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
 $("input").on("keyup",function (){
  s=this.selectionStart;
  e=this.selectionEnd;
  a=this.value.split(" "),b="";
  for (n in a) {
   b+=" "+a[n].substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+a[n].substr(1).toLowerCase();
  }
  this.value=b.substr(1);
  this.selectionStart=s;
  this.selectionEnd=e;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Comment: justo lo que necesitaba, gracias hermano.

Comment: ¿Que hace de diferente?

Comment: Nada solo optimice el código ;))

Comment: ok gracias por la optimizacion  :D